# what is the app for seeing text being typed on a messenger

Tags: mac

i know of a app which pops up a dialog at the top right corner of the screen, when a user in on skype and the other person is typing something.

this is not specific to skype, but for any messenger that is installed on the mac.

i know that the name of the app starts with c but i am not sure if the name is crawl or cawl or something else....

i would really appreciate if someone can help me.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

[**Growl**](http://growl.info)?

Looks like that:

[image: growl tiger]